# Import everything in a Python module inside a function

Tags: python

I would like to construct a function that emulates  `from package_name import *`. While [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4116061/importing-everything-dynamically-from-a-module) answers how one might do so by modifying `globals()`. `globals()`, however, is local to the module the function is defined in.

For example, suppose I define the following function in `first_package.py`,

```
import imp

def load_contents(path):
  """Load everything from another package"""
  module = imp.load_source('', path)
  for k in dir(module):
    if not '__' in k:   # ignore __xxx__ private variables
      globals()[k] = getattr(module, k)
```

Then run the following code in `second_package.py`

```
import first_package

first_package.load_contents('third_package.py')
```

Nothing will happen. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to use `sys._getframe` to go up the call stack 1 step, then retrieve the globals of the caller. The precise code is,

```
def load_contents(path):
  """Load contents of another configuration file"""
  module = imp.load_source('', path)
  glob = sys._getframe(1).f_globals  # globals of calling module
  for k in dir(module):
    if not '__' in k:   # ignore __xxx__ private variables
      glob[k] = getattr(module, k)
```

Note that this code will only work with CPython, as `sys._getframe` is an implementation-specific function.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a dictionary variable within **first_package.py** that is a  cross module variables. Please refer to the link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/142545/python-how-to-make-a-cross-module-variable) on how to go about defining a cross module variable. Refer to the response provided by **J.F.Sebastian**

It is always good to adopt a simple approach that does not play around with python internal mechanisms - since there may be side-effects of such activities in a complex application

Answer (score 0):

You could always pass your callers globals dictionary in to the function and then add to it.