# Can importlib.import_module(m) do `from m import *`?

Tags: python

The file `module_x` has

**module_x.py**

```
A = 'x'
```

And the following script will print 'x' from `module_x.py`, which is what I need.

```
A = 'a'

from module_x import *
print(A)  # x
```

However, I need to dynamically import the module so I use importlib for it. However, the following code prints 'a'.

```
from importlib import import_module

A = 'a'

m = 'module_x'  # m will be passed as a parameter
x = import_module(m) 
print(A)  # a
```

The value of `x.A` is 'x', but I want the `import_module()` to assign A to 'x'.

Comment: Possible dupe [Importing everything ( * ) dynamically from a module](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4116061/674039)

Answer (score 1):

this should do it:

```
globals().update(import_module("module").__dict__)
```

In case you want to import something specific

```
var = import_module("module").var
```

Comment: Don't blindly update globals like that.  The module namespace (i.e. the `__dict__` attribute) usually has a lot more stuff in it than a *-import will take. This may break the importing-from-module by accidentally overwriting a bunch of it's attributes such as `__name__`, `__package__`, `__loader__`, `__spec__`, `__doc__`...

Comment: Will filtering out these `__x__` attributes be good enough?

Comment: @ca9163d9 No.  If `module_x` namespace is within your control, define and `__all__` variable in it and access that.  I don't know any other way to do this with `importlib.import_module`, it doesn't seem to expose *-imports dynamically.